# Attribute value added using Jquery but not visible in view source.How to slove it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('img').attr('alt', 'Alternative text');
```

I am using this code and dynamically added alt attribute value image tag.It will be added image tag.After I check view page source ,that alt attribute value showing empty,

How can I add all image attribute value dynamically and checking  view page source mean added attribute value want show?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

The source code is just that: the *source*.

Changing the DOM generated from the source code doesn't change the original source code.

A DOM Inspector (built into the developer tools of every modern browser) will show you a serialisation of the live DOM though.

Comment: If  I am using php mean it will possiple?

Comment: @ThirumalaiKarthi  yes, then possible

Comment: @ThirumalaiKarthi — If you are generating the HTML server-side (it doesn't matter what language, even if it is JavaScript), then the HTML source will be modified.

Comment: More specifically: modern browsers (well, chrome anyway) do view-source be *reloading* the page from the server.

Comment: @Quentin - I am already generated HTML page statically with multiple image tag..Now I want to add alt tag for all img tag..